# Create a 16 byte array of zeros in swift

Tags: swift

I have to initialize a 16 byte array of Zeros in my Swift Project. In Java its easy to initialize 16 byte array using following code:

```
new byte[16]
```

I need the same code implementation in Swift.
Thanks a lot in advance for any help.
Have a good day!

Comment: What have you tried already?  Please post your work-in-progress implementation.

Comment: So, you want to know how to create an array of zero bytes. You should edit your question to reflect just that, instead of the encryption stuff you have mentioned.

Comment: Hi @JAL , I have tried to initialize variable of type UInt16 in swift as Byte in swift is typedef to UInt16. But when I try to print its size using sizeofValue, it always returns 8 bytes instead  of 16.

Comment: *"as Byte in swift is typedef to UInt16"* – ???? There is no `Byte` type in Swift 2.2. There is `UInt8` though ... What exactly did you do with sizeofValue?

Comment: @MartinR I had a variable of type UInt8 and Uint16 but when I print it using print(sizeofValue(variable)) I get 8 bytes instead of 16 bytes but what I need is a 16 byte array

Answer (score 5):

Use an [UnsafeMutablePointer](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_UnsafeMutablePointer_Structure/index.html). I'd imagine `UInt8` is probably closest to Java's `byte`, so you can allocate space for 20 of those and initialize them to`0` like so...

```
let ptr = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.alloc(20)
ptr.initialize(0)
```

**Edit: Thanks to [vacawama](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1630618/vacawama)**

You can also use a Swift array and the `&` operator to convert it to a pointer, which is syntactically a bit nicer...

```
var arr = [UInt8](count: 20, repeatedValue: 0)
doSomething(&arr)
```

These two methods are functionally equivalent as `&` will convert the array to an `UnsafeMutablePointer` under the hood.

**Note:** Notice that I used the `var` keyword to define the array in the second example, so that the `&` operator converts it to `UnsafeMutablePointer` instead of `UnsafePointer`. Otherwise, you will get a cryptic compiler error if you attempt to mutate the memory

Comment: Out of curiosity (never really used pointers in Swift), when would you prefer the method above over just using a "safe native" array of `UInt8` elements (readily transferable to `NSData`, if we'd so wish)? E.g. `let foo = [UInt8](count: 20, repeatedValue: 0)`.

Comment: You would always prefer the swift Array since its memory will be managed for you. However, there are times (like when you are interfacing with C code) that you need a pointer as opposed to a Swift object in which case you must use UnsafeMutablePointer. For example, you cannot call a C function which takes a pointer as an argument with a native swift type. It's not mentioned explicitly in the question, but I had kind of assumed he needs a pointer since the java equivalent provided will be a pointer.

Comment: I see, it was an honest inquiry and not a pointer (no pun intended), thanks!

Comment: I have used your methods but when ever I try to print the variables size using sizeofValue(), I am always getting 8 bytes instead of 16 bytes. Should I be worried about it?

Comment: This is expected. The value is a pointer (a memory address). You are printing the size of that exact address (the first byte, which is 8) as opposed to the range of all 20

Comment: @CharlieMartin, I disagree with your assertion that you need to create the array as an `UnsafeMutablePointer` to interact with `C`.  You can pass a `UInt8` array as `&arrayName`.  See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH8-ID17

Comment: & will convert a native Swift array to an UnsafeMutablePointer, so they are exactly equivalent

Comment: @vacawama I posted an edit to include your syntactically nicer version. Please correct me if you see any issues. Swift is changing rapidly. I'm trying to keep up!

Comment: The `&arr` can only appear in a call argument list.  You can't do `let ptr = &arr`, but you can call a C function `void doSomething(unsigned char *str)` from Swift with `doSomething(&arr)`.